# Python appending elements to a 2d array with user inputs

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

So what I'm trying to do is generate a number of lists in a 2d array with user inputs. I have that part working I'm just trying to get it to generate an amount of number per list with a user input. For example if the user input for the amount of list is ten and the user input for the amount of number per list is 8 then I should have an output with 10 lists each with 8 different numbers in them.
This is my code:

```
from array import *
import random
array= []



arrayInput = int(input("please input the number of arrays:"))
amountInput = int(input("please enter how many numbers per array"))

for i in range(arrayInput):
    array.insert(1, ):






print("Array after appending of the elements: ")
for x in array:
    for y in x:
        print(y,end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: why are you doing `from array import *`????

Comment: Why is random doing here? do you want the numbers to be random or do you want them just distinct?

Comment: I want the actual numbers within the arrays to be random

Comment: Is their some reason that you want to use `array` rather than a basic Python `list`?  What is the range of the integer values to randomly generate?

Comment: I just need to create a 2d array that has arrays within it and be able to control the amounts with user input

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this than what I am proposing, but I think it should work.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

arrayInput = int(input("please input the number of arrays: \n"))
amountInput = int(input("please enter how many numbers per array: \n"))

arr = np.empty((arrayInput, amountInput))

for i in range(arrayInput):
    for j in range(amountInput):
        arr[i][j] = random.randint(0,9) 

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you're just trying to create a random matrix with input-based size, so you should be fine with:

```py
import numpy as np

arrayInput = int(input("please input the number of arrays:"))
amountInput = int(input("please enter how many numbers per array"))

arr = np.arange(arrayInput * amountInput).reshape(arrayInput, amountInput)
```

Or is there a particular reason to create an array object? my understanding is that the array object doesn't handle nested lists or two-dimensional objects.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a standard Python `list` is what you should use. 2D "arrays" can be implemented as a list of lists, but this is not possible using `array.array()`.

Here's how to use a list comprehension to generate a list of lists containing random integers between 0 and 100:

```
import random

rows = int(input("please input the amount of arrays: "))
cols = int(input("please enter how many numbers per array: "))

array = [[random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
print(array)
```

This generates random values in the range 0-100 inclusive.

Example output for rows = 5, cols = 6:

```
[[74, 93, 96, 67, 10, 27], [69, 73, 12, 47, 11, 1], [25, 11, 11, 87, 4, 93], [14, 68, 88, 62, 80, 43], [12, 7, 56, 92, 100, 20]]
```

Alternatively you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(101, size=(rows, cols))
print(array)
```

Example output for rows = 5, cols = 6:

```
[[58 72 67 64 20]
 [64 48 56 18 13]
 [12 48 20 83 25]
 [98 49 81 32 11]
 [83 45 81 68 17]
 [38 77 17 71 99]]
```